# How do I correctly format my code to run this menu program in Java?

Tags: java, methods, program-entry-point

This is a beginner question. I'm about to start an online bootcamp and am stuck on my last pre-work project (which is a cumulation of everything we've been instructed to self-teach ourselves). I'm really lost and can't wrap my head around this.

Here is what I've come up with so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Objective9Lab5 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner kb = new Scanner (System.in);
        double num1, num2;
        boolean keepGoing = true;
        int choice;
        double answer = 0.0;
    double calcTax;

    System.out.print("Please give me a number: ");
    num1 = kb.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Please give me another number: ");
    num2 = kb.nextDouble();

        while (keepGoing) {
            System.out.print("Which would you like to do? ");
            choice = kb.nextInt();
      double average = findAverage(num1, num2);

            switch (choice) {
        case 1:
          System.out.println(+ num1 + " + " + num2 + " = ");
          break;
        case 2:
          System.out.println("The average of " + num1 + "and" + num2 + "is" + average);
          break;
        case 3:
          System.out.println("The amount in tax to be collected from a purchace of " + num1 + "and " + num2 + "is " + calcTax);
          break;
        case 4: System.out.println("You've chosen to quit.");
          System.exit(0);
          return;
        default:
          System.out.println("Invalid entry. Please try again.");
          selection = scanner.nextInt();
        }
        kb.close();
    }
    public static void printMenu() {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("========= MENU =========");
        System.out.println("|                      |");
        System.out.println("|   1. Add Numbers     |");
        System.out.println("|   2. Find Average    |");
        System.out.println("|   3. Calculate Tax   |");
        System.out.println("|   4. Exit            |");
        System.out.println("|                      |");
        System.out.println("========================");
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static double findSum(double x, double y) {
        double sum = x + y;
        return sum;
  }
  public static double findAverage(double x, double y){
    double average = (x + y) / 2;
    return average;
  }
  public static double findCalcTax(double x, double y){
    double sum * .831
    }
```

My output is supposed to look something like this:

```
Please give me a number: 2
Please give me another number: 8

========= MENU =========
|                      |
|   1. Add Numbers     |
|   2. Find Average    |
|   3. Calculate Tax   |
|   4. Exit            |
|                      |
========================

Which would you like to do? 1
2.0 + 8.0 = 10.0

========= MENU =========
|                      |
|   1. Add Numbers     |
|   2. Find Average    |
|   3. Calculate Tax   |
|   4. Exit            |
|                      |
========================

Which would you like to do? 2
The average of 2.0 and 8.0 is: 5.0

========= MENU =========
|                      |
|   1. Add Numbers     |
|   2. Find Average    |
|   3. Calculate Tax   |
|   4. Exit            |
|                      |
========================

Which would you like to do? 3
The amount in tax to be collected from a purchase of 2.0 and 8.0 is: 0.831

========= MENU =========
|                      |
|   1. Add Numbers     |
|   2. Find Average    |
|   3. Calculate Tax   |
|   4. Exit            |
|                      |
========================

Which would you like to do? 5
Invalid entry.  Please try again

========= MENU =========
|                      |
|   1. Add Numbers     |
|   2. Find Average    |
|   3. Calculate Tax   |
|   4. Exit            |
|                      |
========================

Which would you like to do? 4
You've chosen to quit.
```

I keep getting this error, but for all of the main methods:

```
Objective9Lab5.java:59: error: illegal start of expression
    public static double findSum(double x, double y) {
    ^
```

Comment: The curly brace after `main()` is not close; add a `}` just before the line marked in your question, and it should compile. Afterwards, you can try to reformat accordingly …

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with your code. The first one I noticed is you didn't declare the "selection" variable where you try to assign a value to in the default case.

The error you are facing is due to not closing the main method, you simply missed an "}" after closing the while loop.

Here it is properly closed:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    double num1, num2;
    boolean keepGoing = true;
    int choice;
    double answer = 0.0;
    double calcTax;

    System.out.print("Please give me a number: ");
    num1 = kb.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Please give me another number: ");
    num2 = kb.nextDouble();

    while (keepGoing) {
        System.out.print("Which would you like to do? ");
        choice = kb.nextInt();
        double average = findAverage(num1, num2);

        switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println(+num1 + " + " + num2 + " = ");
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("The average of " + num1 + "and" + num2 + "is" + average);
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("The amount in tax to be collected from a purchace of " + num1 + "and " + num2 + "is " + calcTax);
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("You've chosen to quit.");
                System.exit(0);
                return;
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid entry. Please try again.");
                selection = scanner.nextInt();
        }
        kb.close();
    }
}
```

There are still a few issues with your program, namely logic which you should analyze yourself to develop your programming ability.

Comment: A few other problems: `scanner` is not defined. `System.exit(0);` is unnecessary; returning from `main` is sufficient. `kb.close()` is inappropriate; the `Scanner` was created reading from `System.in`, but that wasn't opened by this close so it should not be closed by this code. Close everything you open; do *not* close anything you *did not* open.